# jQuery UI is disabeling links in SVG image ( xlink:href )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, svg

I have an embedded SVG image which contains some links to external URLs. When adding jQuery UI to the document, the links of the SVG won't work anymore. I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4tdtvaf/1/) to demonstrate the behavoir. When removing jQuery UI from the "External Resources" the links will work.

The SVG links are made like this:

```
<a xlink:href="/hamburg-nord" xlink:title="SomeName">
<path id="nord" d=".....a lot of image-data-coordinates.........."/>
</a>
```

I suspect, it is a bug in jQuery UI. But what can i do to make the links work? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are applying an `accordion` to all the `<a>` elements:

```
$( "#accordion, a, #xxx" ).accordion({...});
```

If you leave them out your SVG links work fine.

```
$( "#accordion, #xxx" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4tdtvaf/3/